Assembly Intel 8086 64-bits operands calculator
Please I need the full program of a calculator that calculates the sum, the subtraction, the multiplication, and the division of 2 operands 64 bits each.
Because the registers in 8086 microprocessor are 16 bits I could not find a way to solve this problem.

Asking for a full program is beyond what you can ask on this forum. We deal with solving specific troubles you might encounter while implementing the task yourself. We don't write all of the code for you!

2 operands 64 bits each.
Because the registers in 8086 microprocessor are 16 bits I could not find a way to solve this problem.

To give you an idea on how to work with numbers that are larger than the normal register size, consider the case where you add the two 64-bit values 0123456789ABCDEFh and 012389ABCDEF4567h:
valueA dw CDEFh, 89ABh, 4567h, 0123h
valueB dw 4567h, CDEFh, 89ABh, 0123h
result dw 0, 0, 0, 0

Without a loop
mov  di, offset result
mov  si, offset valueA
mov  bx, offset valueB
mov  ax, [si]
add  ax, [bx]
mov  [di], ax
mov  ax, [si+2]
adc  ax, [bx+2]    <<<< Note the use of ADC that allows propagating
mov  [di+2], ax          the carry from earlier addition
mov  ax, [si+4]
adc  ax, [bx+4]    <<<< Note the use of ADC that allows propagating
mov  [di+4], ax          the carry from earlier addition
mov  ax, [si+6]
adc  ax, [bx+6]    <<<< Note the use of ADC that allows propagating
mov  [di+6], ax          the carry from earlier addition

With a loop
And using the fact that the values are stored next to each other in memory:
 mov  di, offset result
 mov  si, offset valueA
 mov  cx, 4
 clc             ; No carry to consider in first addition
Next:
 lodsw           ; `mov ax, [ds:si]` `inc si` `inc si`
 adc  ax, [si+6] ; Use ADC to propagate carry from earlier addition
 stosw           ; `mov [es:di], ax` `inc di` `inc di`
 loop Next

Because this is 8086, we don't have to avoid using loop like we would on regular x86 (because there loop is a slow instruction).

Commenting that lodsw and stosw do the equivalent of add to SI or DI could be confusing because these instructions do not alter the Carry Flag, unlike your pseudo-code with add. It may not be terribly useful to a beginner but eg lea si, [si + 2] would reflect that lodsw preserves all flags more accurately.

Oh, your cmp will mess up your Carry Flag. Unlike my first comment this is a correctness error. You have to use either dec or inc combined with a conditional jump, or loop, to preserve the Carry Flag from one iteration to the next. (Or use something like lahf and sahf or pushf and popf.)
